# ArgumentNull Exception - UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

In a ASP MVC application I use the mongodb database as storage for all user data like, logins, claims and so on.
For this I implemented the interfaces and registered them in the microkernel.

Now I've got the following code in the ASP MVC account controller.
When I try to login the userManager finds the user.  But then `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync` throws a `ArgumentNull` exception with the StackTrace below. I can see that it indicates that the value of a claim is null. But all claims the user have do have non null values.

Is there perhaps a claim which is expected I'm possibly missing ?

**Code:**

```
   AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

if (user != null)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe }, identity);
```

**ExceptionStack:**

> ```
> [ArgumentNullException: Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein. Parametername:value]
> System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType,
> String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey,
> String propertyValue) +11996035
> System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value) +36   
> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +1599   
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +99   
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +58    
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  +28
> GP.CRM.Web.Controllers.&lt;DoLogin&gt;d__10.MoveNext() in 
>    D:\dev\crm\CRM\src\Web\GP.CRM.Web\GP.CRM.Web.Api\Controllers\AccountController.cs:58
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Just found it after searching whole day.

The **SecurityStamp**Field was "null" and not a empty string. Not sure wether this is related to mongodb. as Null is a "Null" FieldType and not a string field. but after setting at least a empty string it works.